# List comprehension using two lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If I have a list like this (Notice that it skips one after `5`, `12`, `19`, `26` .. etc. So `6`, `13`, `20`, `27` are all missing) :

```
lst1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61]
```

And I have a list like this (this represents which skips)

```
lst2 = [0,2] # this means the 0'st skip and 2nd skip which is 13)
```

And combining the `lst1` and `lst2`,

I want to make a new `lst3` that has `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

I don't know if my explanation made sense, but I basically want to use values from two lists and make a new list. This is what I've tried:

```
lst1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61]

def colorChecker(color):
    for c in color: 
    return 6 + 7 * color

lst3 = [ p for p in lst1 if p < colorChecker([0,2])]
```

This only seems to work for `colorChecker[0]`, not `colorChecker[1]`.

Comment: So...what have you tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting us to show you teh codez

Comment: lst 3= [ p for p in playablePieces if p < colorChecker(playingColors)]

Comment: @jonrsharpe please check the edited main thread! Thanks

Comment: Somewhere you are probably going to have to have `for whatever in [0, 2]`. You can't just pass a list to a function and expect it to go *"Oh, I guess they mean call the function recursively"*. Split this into multiple steps: 1. Break up `lst1` into contiguous sections; 2. Index into the new list of lists to get the parts you need; and 3. Join them back together. Don't try to put it all in one line, that helps nobody.

Comment: *Sigh* you can only `return` **once** from a function. Once you do that, wherever you were in whatever loops, it's over. Stop trying to do this in a single line.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please check again!

Answer (score 1):

If you already know where the missing elements will be, there's *no need at all* for `lst1`. Your code becomes as simple as:

```
>>> lst2 = [0, 2]
>>> lst3 = []
>>> for i in lst2:
        lst3.extend(range(7*i, 7*i+6))


>>> lst3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: Good point about using `range()`; I foolishly assumed that the given definition of `lst1` was just an absurdly minimized example. :-}

Answer (score 0):

Since each element in `lst2` appears to reference a group of 6 elements from `lst1`, I'd first create a list of those chunks like

```
[lst1[i*6:(i+1)*6] for i in lst2]
```

...which evaluates to

```
== [lst1[0*6:(0+1)*6], lst1[2*6:(2+1)*6]]
== [lst1[0:6], lst1[12:18]]
== [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Finally, you can just [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) that list to get your result.